# Decode base64 array of bytes to txt file - iPhone

Tags: iphone, encoding, byte, base64, text-files

I'm geting an array of bytes (it's a txt file) from a server that I need to save at my app's documents folder. I,ve tried many solutions I found and I managed to save the file, but the encoding appears to be wrong, when I try to view the contents of the txt file saved the first line says:

<.base64Binary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">

...then about 50 lines of random characters until the document ends with:

<./base64Binary>

I've tried decoding the NSData to nsstring using some examples i've found, but none could solve this problem

thanks

I've tried this solutions:

http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?BaseSixtyFour

http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/06/base64-encoding-options-on-mac-and.html

Comment: Did you feed just those 'random characters' to the base64 decode functions or did you include the xml tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved it!! Using part of the code in

http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/06/base64-encoding-options-on-mac-and.html

into my classes and parsing the xml before encoding.